# Обновить не активную Activity или обновить adpter в неактивной

Tags: java, android, activity, adapter, update

Это мой код в неактивной активити для обновления адаптера, но когда вызываю его из другой активити выдает: Приложение mypo остановлено !

```
public void listUpdate(){

        resList = DBController.memoDB.getAllList();
        val.clear();
            for (int i = 0;i<resList.getCount();i++) {
                val.add(resList.getString(1));
                resList.moveToNext();
            }
        Collections.sort(val);
        //adapter.clear();
        //Создаем адаптер с вектором переменных
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, val);
        //Вывод адаптера в лист

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Не надо обновлять неактивную активити. Сделайте обновление в методе ```onResume```.

Comment: @temq Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @temq Отлично все работает)

Answer (score 2):

Не надо обновлять неактивную активити. Это может привести к различным ошибкам и утечкам памяти. Для обновления списка необходимо использовать методы жизненного цикла `Activity`, например `onResume`.